# Pointwise convergence of a particular sequence

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation

We suppose that $f_n\colon X\to [0,\infty]$ are functions and we consider the sequence $\{f_n\}$. For all $n\in \mathbb{N}$ we define $$g_n(x):=\max\left\{f_1(x),\dots, f_n(x)\right\}.$$ It's clear that $g_n\le g_{n+1}$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Now, if we define $$f(x):=\sup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} \{f_n(x)\},$$

> Why $$\Large g_n \to f\quad\text{pointwise}\quad \text{for}\quad n\to\infty $$

Comment: It's the same as asking why $b_n = \max\{a_1,...,a_n\}$ converges to $a:=\sup_{n \in \mathbb N_+} a_n$ for sequence $(a_n)_n$ of non-negative real numbers. Of course $b_n$ is non-decreasing, hence it converges to some limit $b$, and it's obvious that $b \le a$ (because $b_n \le a$ for any $n \in \mathbb N_+$). Can you try the other inequality?

Comment: @DominikKutek, yes, because $a_n\le b_n$ for all $n$ and then $\sup a_n\le \sup b_n=b$